# Django model database look up

Tags: django

I am generating video files triggered by POST request and saving them programmatically into the django model below.

How can I look up the uploaded file itself once uploaded to the database in a similar fashion to VideoUpload.objects(get)?

I don't have users only guests. I am using [hash-id-field](https://github.com/nshafer/django-hashid-field) so far however can change this.

```
Models.py

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
import hashlib 
from hashid_field import HashidAutoField


class VideoUpload(models.Model):
    hashed_video_file_name = HashidAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True)

    objects = models.Manager()
```

Comment: How do you want to look up the uploaded file? What do you want to query by?

Comment: Can I do it by hashed_video_file_name? I am trying things like VideoUpload.objects.get(hashed_video_file_name)

Comment: The purpose of getting the id is so that I can then assign a session to a created video and serve it to the user who created it.